# Fixing LVM boot after disk clone

Tags: linux, lvm, grub2

I have a NVME boot disk that was running low on space in my proxmox server. After using Clonezilla to clone the disk to another larger NVME things are unstable.

The boot disk has 2 Logical volumes on it, and seems to get through the boot process fine, albeit with a few errors.

[image: initial boot errors]

After booting to the login screen, a number of issues arise:

- logging in causes the screen to flash and then reshow the login screen.
- a number of write errors begin appearing in the terminal

What have i done wrong here?

[image: write errors]

Comment: what device is `/dev/sdd`? what about dev `dm-1`? what is device `1022:1453`

Comment: Please, boot from recovery media and run `lsblk` and `lspci`.